# No non-expired provisioning profiles were found

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]
I cannot test my app on my device, the error that I'm seeing is the one shown in the image. 
Even if I choose my account for Team I get the following message `"An App ID with Identifier 'identifier' is not available. Please enter a different string."`. I haven't enrolled to Apple's membership, but on my other mac this wasn't occurring. In my keychain access the certificates are installed but no provisioning profiles yet because I don't have any of them as soon as I'm free user.

Comment: Have you added the provisioning file to the xCode? If you have the certificate that's mean you should have the provisioning profile which is in the Apple Member centre.

Comment: I dont have provisioning profile because i'm a free not enrolled member and just a certificate is installed automatically. And in Apple Member centre I dont see Certificates/Profiles/App ids etc etc. tabs

Comment: What are the steps you are using to create the issue?

Comment: Are you creating an App, then you connect your device and try to run it on it? What xCode version you are using.?

Comment: I just create new project and connect my device. Then I set up my team to be my own appleId and when i try to run the blank app on the device i got that error. Is so weird because it is working on my mini mac but not on my iMac. Using latest XCode version.

Comment: Let me clarify to you what team means, You must have an Apple certificate assigned with provisioning profile where your team have. Otherwise, it is impossible to run it on the device. Setting your team as your own AppleID without cert and provisioning won't work. I just tested it even though I have 3 teams with valid certs.

Comment: Hmmm.... dont know how but you should see my case :) give me skype or smth pls Mine is my name and surname together lowercase

Comment: Ok, have you tried exporting your xCode account from mini mac and importing it to your iMac? I'm not sure how it is working on your mini mac. try it and let me know.

Comment: I haven't done that. Apparently i will do that tomorrow when I get to work. But how to export the account? Do you mean from keychain access? I did for the certificate and the private key

Comment: no, Use this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html. After you export the account, reimport it to your iMac.

Comment: Oh, importing the working one fixed the issue. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion.

Importing the developer account from the working machine resolved the issue:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html