# How to resolve this error Xcode7.3?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I want too Generate my .ipa file but its showing on

> ERROR:"Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired
>   provisioning profiles were found."

Step:1 I had created apple ID
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No non-expired provisioning profiles were found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218497/no-non-expired-provisioning-profiles-were-found)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `App Store` or `AdHoc` provisioning profile using your `Distribution Certificate` from Apple Developers Portal. Without these, you cannot create a `.ipa` file for testing. While creating those, you also get chance to select the devices on which you will be allowed to test the `.ipa` file. And for all this, you will need a paid developer's account.

If you have paid developers account then I will suggest you to go to developer's portal and revoke all the certificates and start from scratch, i.e., from from create bundle identifier.

There is a good [guide by Parse](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/iOS) to setup all this for push notification. You may follow it, excluding the certificate uploading section and try to resolve your problem.

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, ‘9.0’
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'MapViewDemo' do

pod ’Stripe’
pod ‘Applepay’

end

target 'MapViewDemoTests' do




end

Answer (score 0):

I've made a similar problem. How I fixed it was to login on the apple developer web site to apply and download a profile for your app.

After double-click the download file , you can see the file in organization of the project in Xcode.The name of the bundle id is the type like com.yourname.appname

Move to Target -> General and select the correct Team.

Now go to Project Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity and select just 'iOS Developer' and 'Automatic' in Provisioning Profiles. Your app should now compile and run smoothly.

Hope this helps.